# HTTP resumable download on Ejabberd and Conversations (Android)

Tags: android, ejabberd, omemo

I am running a small Ejabberd server for my company. Company has around 20+ users which share files over Convesations (Android) using this server. In the recent updates of the Conversations, there was new feature of resumable downloads. This feature isn't working with Conversations. When I checked the code, I found that Conversations tries to resume the download by asking server about the ranges, by setting the `Range` property in header, but Ejabberd server doesn't respond with `Content-Range`. Absence of this header field is making it fail to resume the download. I checked `mod_http_upload` and `mode_http_fileserver`, but I didn't find any option for setting this setting for the Conversations. Do I have to offload file download/upload to separate PHP Server or Ejabberd support range based partial downloads?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, ejabberd's HTTP services do not support Range, as it's a simple HTTP service.

If you need this or other advanced features, you should try to use a dedicated HTTP server.

Comment: It seems like I have to configure separate HTTP server for this. Thank you for the clarification.